Call worksheet in macros
I'm getting a issue, in B column there is duplicate data, it have different enrichment value, this code is working but only printing a single value from enrichment when its call from Account_No (Column B)
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    ' This event will now remain empty if you want to avoid searching on each character change.
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' Call the search function when the textbox loses focus
    Call SearchAccount
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    ' Check if the Enter key is pressed
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Call SearchAccount
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SearchAccount()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim accountNo As String
    Dim accountName As String
    Dim found As Range
    Dim enrichmentLabels As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    Set enrichmentLabels = New Collection

    ' Open the workbook from which we need to fetch the data
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("E:\Test1.xlsx") ' Change the path to your actual workbook path
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your actual sheet name
    
    ' Get the account number from TextBox3
    accountNo = Me.TextBox3.Text
    
    ' Search for the account number in the range B2:B1169
    Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
    Set found = rng.Find(What:=accountNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' If found, display the corresponding account name in Label13
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        accountName = found.Offset(0, 1).Value 'first value (0, 1)
        Me.Label13.Caption = accountName
        
        enrichmentCode = found.Offset(0, 3).Value
        enrichmentLabel = found.Offset(0, 4).Value
        
        ' Store the enrichment label in the collection
        enrichmentLabels.Add enrichmentLabel
        
        ' Disable all enrichment labels
        For i = 1 To 18
            Dim labelControl As Control
            On Error Resume Next ' Add this line to skip over any errors if a control is not found
            Set labelControl = Me.Controls("LabelE" & i)
            If Not labelControl Is Nothing Then
                labelControl.Enabled = False
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Resets normal error handling
        Next i
        
        ' Print all enrichment labels
        For Each enrichmentLabel In enrichmentLabels
            On Error Resume Next ' Temporarily resume next on error to handle if the object doesn't exist
            Set labelControl = Me.Controls("Label" & enrichmentCode)
            
            If labelControl Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Error: Control Label" & enrichmentCode & " does not exist."
            Else
                labelControl.Caption = enrichmentLabel
                labelControl.Enabled = True
            End If
            
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default behavior
        Next enrichmentLabel
    Else
        Me.Label13.Caption = "Account not found."
    End If
    
    ' Close the workbook without saving changes
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Input

Output

It want to show all the enrichment that store in column F

use a collection or an array to store all the enrichment labels found for the account number then loop through

You only run enrichmentLabels.Add enrichmentLabel once, so why would you expect more values to be listed?  You need to loop over the other matches for accountNo and collect the other labels.

Maybe you can explain a little exactly how your label controls are named? Are they called "E01", "E02" etc?


Collection is not necessary for your case.
Add a Do Loop to search all acount# in Col B

Private Sub SearchAccount()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim accountNo As String
    Dim accountName As String
    Dim found As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    ' Dim enrichmentLabels As Collection
    ' Set enrichmentLabels = New Collection
    ' Open the workbook from which we need to fetch the data
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("E:\Test1.xlsx") ' Change the path to your actual workbook path
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your actual sheet name
    ' Get the account number from TextBox3
    accountNo = Me.TextBox3.Text
    ' Disable all enrichment labels
    For i = 1 To 18
        Dim labelControl As Control
        On Error Resume Next ' Add this line to skip over any errors if a control is not found
        Set labelControl = Me.Controls("LabelE" & i)
        If Not labelControl Is Nothing Then
            labelControl.Enabled = False
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Resets normal error handling
    Next i
    ' Search for the account number in the range B2:B1169
    Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
    Set found = rng.Find(What:=accountNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' If found, display the corresponding account name in Label13
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        accountName = found.Offset(0, 1).Value 'first value (0, 1)
        Me.Label13.Caption = accountName
        Dim firstAddress As String
        firstAddress = found.Address
        Do
            enrichmentCode = found.Offset(0, 3).Value
            enrichmentLabel = found.Offset(0, 4).Value
            On Error Resume Next ' Temporarily resume next on error to handle if the object doesn't exist
            Set labelControl = Me.Controls("Label" & enrichmentCode)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default behavior
            If labelControl Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Error: Control Label" & enrichmentCode & " does not exist."
            Else
                labelControl.Caption = enrichmentLabel
                labelControl.Enabled = True
            End If
            Set found = rng.FindNext(found) ' search next acct in Col B
        Loop While (Not found Is Nothing) And found.Address <> firstAddress
    Else
        Me.Label13.Caption = "Account not found."
    End If
    ' Close the workbook without saving changes
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

